# Is it possible to create a cell inside an HTML table with TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm actually writing a templating tool that will be able to read a test / quiz written inside a properly-formatted text file and then render it on both paper (by generating a PDF file) and for the web (by creating HTML + CSS + JS). To generate PDF files I have chosen TCPDF, but I'm actually having a problem: Sometimes I'd like to create tables and put checkboxes and textboxes inside of them, just like as you can see in this *mock-up image*:

[image: This is a representation of my problem]

If I were to do it in HTML I would simply create some  or  tags and apply a border on them by using the related CSS property, for example by writing something like this:

```
<style>
    .dashed {
        border: 2px dashed gray;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    .solid {
        border: 2px solid gray;
        padding-left: .75em;
        padding-right: .75em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: .5em;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    .solid:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
</style>

<table border="2" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>What does 1 + 1 ?</td>
        <td><span class="dashed">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>What does 2 + 2 ?</td>
        <td>
            <span class="solid">A</span>
            One
            <span class="solid">B</span>
            Two
            <span class="solid">C</span>
            Three
            <span class="solid">D</span>
            Four
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(I'm actually using inline CSS for explanation purposes, I don't usually apply CSS styles this way)

**Unfortunately, if I'm not mistaken, TCPDF doesn't support CSS Borders** - so I'm feeling a little bit lost. Would you give me some hints and your opinion about what I could do in order to achieve the same result?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `dompdf` before?you should try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using HTML border tags?  eg: `border="2"` `bordercolor="yellow"` `bgcolor="red"`